# Dual Monitor Setup Weird Problem in Linux Mint 19.2

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia, cinnamon, multi-monitor

I'm running **Linux Mint 19.2 Cinnamon** (**4.15.0-70-generic** kernel) with **NVIDIA Corporation GM206 GeForce GTX 960**. I'm facing a  weird problem with dual monitor setup including two **Dell P2212H** monitors, both with **DVI** and **VGA** ports.
Everything is working fine when I'm using following configuration:

1. First monitor is connected to my PC using **DVI-D <-> DVI-D** cable.
2. Second monitor is connected to my PC using **HDMI to VGA** adapter and **VGA <-> VGA** cable.

```
inxi -Gx
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GM206 [GeForce GTX 960] vendor: Micro-Star MSI 
  driver: nvidia v: 435.21 bus ID: 01:00.0 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: nvidia 
  unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa 
  resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz, 1920x1080~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GTX 960/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 435.21 
  direct render: Yes
```

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      59.94  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Dual monitor setup is working fine but because there is a visible difference in display quality, I have purchased **HDMI <-> DVI-D** cable. Why if I change the cable between my PC and 2nd monitor I can't get dual monitor setup to work? It looks like that with the bellow setup, my PC is no longer able to detect the second monitor.

1. First monitor is connected to my PC using **DVI-D <-> DVI-D** cable.
2. Second monitor is connected to my PC using **HDMI <-> DVI-D** cable.

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I can confirm that **HDMI <-> DVI-D** cable is functional as I tested it on a different PC running Windows 10. Any advice?

Thanks,
Kris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this using @roblm advice from Mint Forum.

```
sudo touch /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Open the file for editing: `xed admin:///etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Add these lines:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
   Identifier   "Layout0"
   Screen   0 "Screen0" 0 0 
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
   Identifier    "Monitor0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
   Identifier   "Device0"
   Driver   "nvidia"        
   BusID  "PCI:1:0:0"
   Option "ConnectedMonitor" "DFP, DFP"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
   Identifier   "Screen0"
   Device   "Device0"
   Monitor   "Monitor0"
   DefaultDepth   24
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Monitor 1, connected by HDMI @ 1920x1080 and Monitor 2, VGA but wouldn't increase from 1600x900 ( to 1920x1080 ).

I followed this article https://www.wikihow.com/Configure-X11-in-Linux ( I'm pretty new to Linux as a  Desktop ), which shows how to create an xorg.conf file. There were some errors when it created but I found a copy in /home/ as xorg.conf.new and I had to copy it to /etc/X11 as xorg.conf.

After rebooting it populated with all the resolutions, I needed to change my VGA-0 entry to allow for a better resolution (1920x1080) on my second monitor.

I then used the Nvidia X Server Settings app (which merged into the xorg.conf file ) app and the Display applet, to change the resolution/orientation etc.. and it worked.

I did a lot of reading and there are many people with problems on 19.x with dual monitors. In previous distro's based on Ubuntu 16.04, the xorg.conf file was already created and therefore editable in first instance.
I'm not saying it was the best way, but for me it worked and is good enough, although if anyone has a better suggestion, I'm willing to learn :-)